# jQuery mobile dialog box source code for Windows Phone?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I was developing an app for windows phone. I was displaying html pages in my app. I wanna use jQuery mobile dialog box in my html pages. So, I went through [jquerymobile.com](http://jquerymobile.com). Since, am very new to this, I cant understand anything from that.

Can anyone please tel me what should i do to have jquery mobile dialog box in my html page ?

Comment: Dialog widget will be deprecated in v1.4, use popup widget instead.

Answer (score 2):

are you using jQuery mobile throughout your app? Or do you want just the dialog box?

If you are working with jQuery mobile, you can do this in markup only. Just have a look at the following code; this is the page you want your popup to appear (HTML):

```
<body>
    <!-- This is your main page -->
    <div data-role="page">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Page Title</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <!-- This is the link that will open your popup.
            You can use either a anchor link to an id existing on this page,
            or you can reference a filename like "popup.html"-->
            <a href="#popup" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-role="button">Open dialog</a>     
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>Page Footer</h4>
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- This is your popup "page" -->
    <div data-role="page" id="popup">

        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>This is your popup header</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
             This is your popup content
             <a href="#" data-role="button">Do something here</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

I have made a working example at jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mwfire/qaNZD/

Do not forget to include all scripts and css, explained at "[anatomy of a page](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/pages/)" section of the documentation.

And have (again) a look at the documentation for options:
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/dialog/

Comment: I like this. but i want to use this for local host. so can you please tel me what are js files i have to download and from where ?

Comment: You can use the hosted versions of jQuery & jQuery mobile and the css
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`

You can find more [here](http://jquerymobile.com/download/)